# Getting a Fresh install from SNAP when application files were deleted

Tags: mysql

I had some files on MYSQL-workbench-community corrupted, an accident involving overly-zealous AppArmor settings, a toy dropped on my keyboard by 5yo granddaughter, a power failure and a liquid lunch (not actually the last one, but there were cans of liquid lunch in the room. so ...)
When Workbench wouldn't run, I removed it: rm -rf. This was a mistake because snap won't reinstall Workbench --Snap says it's already installed. Belatedly, I tried snap remove, which quit when it couldn't find the files I had already deleted. Various switch combinations with snap refresh didn't work, either. If I changed my computer's name and went to a coffee shop for a new ip addrress, would that do it? Is there a config file to edit?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the exact details. Apart from the liquid spill, it's hard to tell what exactly you did with the device. Consider using `monospace` formatting for the commands that you executed so that we can tell it apart from your narrative

Comment: Details that should be provided include your OS & release  Is this a server system? desktop system? what release? etc

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes be resolved by first downgrading to a previous version of the snap using `revert`, which may restore the missing files/directories:

```
sudo snap revert <snap-package>
```

Once this is done, you can remove the snap:

```
sudo snap remove <snap-package>
```

Finally, if you want the snap installed again, simply follow the standard installation:

```
sudo snap install <snap-package>
```

**Note:** This will not work if the snap has never received an update since its first installation.